# Running wildcard subdomain virtualhost from a vagrant box with dnsmasq

Tags: apache-2.2, wildcard, dnsmasq

I'm trying to run a server on [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com). I have the standard lucid32 box up and running with dnsmasq installed. I want to be able to browse to the server from my host computer with a url like anything.dev I have the following option in my dnsmasq config:

```
address=/dev/127.0.0.1
```

And my apache VirtualHost:

```
NameVirtualHost anything.dev:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www

    ServerName anything.dev:80
    ServerAlias *.anything.dev

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

I have my network preferences on my host computer pointing to 33.33.33.10 (the default ip address for the vagrant box). I can view the default site at the static IP address, but anything.dev gives me nothing. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Does the `x.anything.dev` name resolve to the system? (is it in DNS or another name resolution method?)